# P-values for two tailed binomial test exceed 1

Tags: statistics, distribution, p-value, hypothesis-test

Say I want to test if a coin is fair.

An experiment is performed to determine whether a coin flip is fair (50% chance
of landing heads or tails) or unfairly biased, either toward heads (> 50% chance of
landing heads) or toward tails (< 50% chance of landing heads). Since we consider both biased alternatives, a two-tailed test is performed.

H0 = Coin is fair

H1 = Coin is unfair

Here is the experiment result: 10 Heads and 10 Tails

Then I calculate the probability of events assume H0 the coin is fair

The probability of exactly, or more than, 10 Heads out of 20 tosses is p = .588

By symmetry, the probability of exactly, or more than, 10 Tails out of 20 tosses is the same, .588

Thus, the p-value for the coin turning up the same face 10 times out of 20 total flips is .588 + .588 = 1.176 > 1

But p-value cannot be larger than 1, may I know what is wrong here?

Ref:

[PROBABILITY VALUE (p-Value)](https://library.unimelb.edu.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0006/1924161/p_value.pdf)

[Binomial Test Calculator](https://www.socscistatistics.com/tests/binomial/default2.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Case of 10 Heads + 10 Tails is accounted for in both probabilities.

You can see that P(10T) = 0.176, and 0.588 + 0.588 = 1.176 = 1 + P(10T + 10H)

Answer (score 0):

The general relationship for summing event probabilities is

> P(A∪B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A∩B)

Expressed in words, you can only use a simple sum of probabilities for disjoint events.

Your events are A = {#Heads ≥ 10} and B = {#Tails ≥ 10}. {#Tails ≥ 10} => {#Heads ≤ 10}, which makes it clear that the two events are not disjoint because they both include the outcome {#Heads = 10}. Your claim that the probability exceeds 1 fails because you've neglected that intersection term, which has P{#Heads = 10} = 0.176.